# VB.net For loop weirdness?

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop

So I decided to play with VB.net some, and the for loops seem to be horribly inaccurate.
That, or I'm doing something wrong. Can someone assist me in my issue here?

```
Private Sub forLoop()
    For i = 0 To 10 Step 1
        'Do stuff
    Next i
End Sub
```

It seems to go through that anywhere between 3k to 200 times depending on what I have it do...
Shouldn't it only go through that loop 10 times? I'm used to java, sorry if this is a super dumb question.

Comment: Please post the contents of the `Do stuff` placeholder. Is it possible that you're altering the value of the `i` variable? I see that you're not declaring the `i` value in your For loop, which suggests that you're using it elsewhere.

Comment: I'm just checking it with SendKeys.Send() and putting it in a notepad++ document to see how many lines it creates. With another Sendkey for "enter" ofc.

Comment: We can't help you further without more code from your project. What happens when you set a debugger breakpoint for your loop body? Does the breakpoint get hit 10 times or more? Do you have multiple threads running the same function code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RmTTiP0A - This is all I have done. I just want it to send text from the text field 10 times.

Comment: I see nothing in your code that explains this behaviour. I suggest you use your debugger and set a breakpoint.

Answer (score 2):

The sendkeys is triggering the Button.Click event, so your app is in an infinite loop.

Comment: I'm calling the Sub forLoop() when I click a button, and only clicking the button once. Do you think its because of the way I'm calling it?

Comment: SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}") is clicking the button. You need to change the input focus to the wherever you want the text to go.

Comment: Even if I click away to a textbox does it still hit enter on the button to start the loop?

Comment: Yes, when you click the button the first time, it sets the input focus to the button, and then the forloop function keeps sending text and clicking that button. you need to set the target of the sendkeys at the beginning of the forloop function.

Comment: Ohh okay I see what you mean, thanks alot man. Really helped :)